# Set up a loop that renames tables along the way

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, sql-server-2012, rename

I have a SQL query (SSMS 2012) that uses three tables, let's call them table1_chunk_1, table2_chunk_1 and table3_chunk_1.  I would like to set up a method to achieve the following:

1. Do a bunch of stuff using the three tables with the suffix _chunk_1.
2. Rename the three tables with the suffix _chunk_2, and do the same bunch of stuff again.
3. Rename the three tables with the suffix _chunk_3, and do the same bunch of stuff again.
4. Repeat until the renaming and bunch of stuff has been done x times (say, 10), so the final set of tables will be named table1_chunk_10, table2_chunk_10 and table3_chunk_10.

Basically, I want to set up something that updates the names to ***_chunk_z as the loop restarts, where z = 1, 2, ..., x.

Comment: This is usually a sign of a broken data model - you've got multiple tables that contain the same "type" of data (such that it makes sense to process them identically). Usually what you should have is a single table and additional column(s) that store the *data* that is probably currently encoded in the table names.

Comment: only way to do this would be with dynamic sql

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using SSMS 2012.  Thanks.

Comment: HINT: sp_msforeachtable